# Find a subset with sum within a range

Tags: algorithm, math

How can I find a subset of an array that the sum of its elements is within a given range?

For example:

```
let a = [ 1, 1, 3, 6, 7, 50]
let b = getSubsetSumRange(3, 5)
```

so b could potentially be [1, 1, 3], [1, 3], [3], [1, 3]; It doesn't matter the order I only need one of them.

Comment: Is it really that unconstrained? Why aren't you just walking the array and picking the first acceptable value?

Comment: It's perhaps to do that after sorting the array?

Comment: Well the thing is, yes, sorting would be the first step for sure, that's why I wrote it already sorted. The problem is that there might not be a single element within the range and I might have to resort to use 2 or more. For the case, I am working on it will be very likely that it'll be a subset of elements rather than a single element

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: How can I apply the subset sum problem to a range though?

Comment: If the range includes 0, is the empty set `[]` a valid result?

Comment: Are the values in the set always > 0?, >= 0?  Could the range include < 0?

Answer (score 2):

You would probably like to use dynamic programming approach to solve this problem.

Let `F[i][j]` have value `true` if it is possible to select some numbers among numbers from the original subset `a[1..i]` so that their sum is equal to j.

`i` would obviously vary from `1` to length of `a`, and `j` from `0` to `max` inclusively, where `max` is the second number from your given range.

`F[i][0] = true` for all `i` by definition (you can always select empty subset).

Then `F[i][j] = F[i - 1][j - a[i]] | F[i - 1][j]`

Logically it means that if you can select a subset with sum `j` from elements `1..i-1`, then you obviously can do it with the subset `1..i`, and if you can select a subset with sum `j - a[i]` from elements `1..i-1`, then by adding your new element `a[i]` to that subset, you can get your desired sum `j`.

After you have calculated the values of `F`, you can find any `F[n][j]` that is `true` for values `j` lying in your desired range.

Say you have found such number `k`. Then the algorithm to find the required set would look like that:

```
for i = n..1:
    if F[i - 1][k - a[i]] == True then
         output a[i] to the answer
         k -= a[i]
         if k == 0
             break
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers this question

Comment: For every number in your range you can check if it is possible to get a subset with the corresponding sum

Comment: i don't know if that'll help me, sounds super inefficient. I am dealing with ranges of up to hundreds